# Is a report used to report, or does a report report? Active vs passive

Tags: grammar, american-english, passive-voice, active-voice

PASSIVE VOICE - The Random Name Report (RANAR) is used to report the randomness and effectiveness of names.

vs.

ACTIVE VOICE - The Random Name Report (RANAR) reports the randomness and effectiveness of names.

My coworkers and I have been debating this point when we write a yearly report.

Arguments for Passive Voice:

- One coworker says that the report is not the "actor", we are.
- We present this report to several groups of people, who then extract from it the necessary information and compile their own reports that make their way up the corporate ladder. Thus, the report is presented, or used to report, implying that we are the actors.

Arguments for Active Voice:

- Industry-wide conventions, principles, and procedures dictate that we should use Active Voice.
- I argue that we aren't necessarily the actor and that the actor is vague. Or that the report can act for itself, even if we have (countless) meetings to present the contents.
- One would assume that a report does exactly what it's name implies: it reports something. Right?!?!

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: The word is not actor, it is agent: The Random Name Report (RANAR) is used [by staffers or by whomever] to report the randomness and effectiveness of names. Versus Staffers use RANAR to report etc. –

Comment: The first example is not passive in the sense that _report_ is an active verb in both examples. The only difference here is that you added a passive filler verb _is used to_ that isn't there in the second example. The actual active would be _One uses the RANAR to report the randomness and effectiveness of names._  A real passive of the second sentence would be _The randomness and effectiveness of names is reported by the RANAR_. Clearly, you don't understand what _passive_ means. So probly you shouldn't talk about it until you find out.

Comment: @JohnLawler Regardless if I didn't truly use passive or active or know what I'm talking about, the argument still stands whether one form is preferable to another. There are lots of writing rules in my industry, and they are frequently broken because people don't know how to write, or don't bother to ask questions like I am now. The difficulty we come across most often is that we can't specify the actor when writing in active voice, as it isn't any one specific person or team. But we're also discouraged from using passive. Hence the struggle

Comment: Ah, that means this is a matter of opinion, which is out of our province.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't see how this is a matter of opinion when there are industry rules dictating the proper way of writing. I came here seeking suggestions and advice, not criticism and ignorance.